# Sanitizing data using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, mysqli

I learned the following method to sanitize data

```
function sanitize($data)
{
return mysql_real_escape_string( $data);
}
```

Then the deprecation of some extension within mysql is becoming abit frustrating for beginners that did not know about it, however it is a learning experience to know PHP properly.  It is recommended to use **mysqli_real_escape_string** instead and since this function requires 2 parameters, I have the following

```
function sanitize($data){

  // 1. Create a database connection
  $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','somepass','secured_login');      
  if($db->connect_errno){
      $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.';   
      die ($connect_error);
  }
   return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data)));
}
```

However, I have been getting the sense that many PHP programmers **highly** recommend using PDO method instead

My apology for such a long intro my question is... Is it safe to use the modified function sanitize where **mysqli_real_escape_string** is used instead **mysql_real_escape_string**?

if not!! then by using PDO I would need to learn OOP PHP instead of procedural.  I hope I framed this question correctly.  Is mixing both programming orientations (procedural and OOP) frowned upon.

What is the real advantage of using PDO in the longer?  Thank you!

Comment: Don't! If you're using MySQLi, use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: Mark, so I need to disregard using the function sanitize all together and using prepared statements instead when using mysqli, did I get that right

Comment: Your `sanitize()` function will repeatedly instantiate new database objects. You'd be better passing the database object in as an argument, as in `$result = sanitize($db, $data)`, or something similar. It's unwise to mix OOP and procedural approaches. It might work, but it'll confuse you or someone like you if the code needs to be maintained.

Comment: The *very fact* that you are using `htmlentities` *and* `strip_tags` in *addition* to `mysql_real_escape_string` means **important concepts are not understood**. The functions serve *different purposes*, adding the extra functions does not make anything "more secure". The best approach is to use placeholders, but failing that, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` *directly on the data* before it is used in an SQL string. (`htmlentites` should be used when *outputting HTML*, but not here; `stripslashes` has some cases, but not here or with HTML.)

Comment: user2864740, you mean I should use **mysqli_real_escape_string** instead becasue **mysql_real_escape_string** id deprecated in future PHP versions

Comment: @user3001162 You [*should* use placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and forget about this awful `sanitize` method. (But yes, that was a typo on my part - *avoid* using deprecated methods.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you have to learn how to use PDO driver to prevent an Headache by reinventing the wheel.
With a OOP driver like PDO you can also do cool stuffs simply by extending the class overring some method and changin few lines of code.
You can also play with dependency-injected PDO derived Objects.
You can change the type of you database by editing the PDO::engine variable.

Plus you can easily prevent SQL iniections of 1st type